# Set up Angular 6 environment variables from .env

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

There's an angular 6 project using environment variables from `./project/src/environments/environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  testVar: 'gg',
};
```

The backend for this project also has env variables in a `.env` file, so a lot of variable duplicate angular env variables. It would be nice to have something like

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  testVar: process.env.TEST_VAR
};
```

, so I didn't have to duplicate variables.

ie

I'd like to parse variables from a `.env` file and assign their values to angular env variables during typescript compilation on the server.

How can this be done?
Maybe with webpack?

**UPDATE**

Some clarification. My .env file contains no json. It looks like this:

```
TEST_VAR=1
```

**UPDATE**

Since [ng eject is not available for Angular 6](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject), I don't seem to be able to hack into webpack config. Looks like deadend here.

> ng eject
>
> Overview
>
> Temporarily disabled.
>
> Ejects your app and output the
> proper webpack configuration and scripts.

Comment: any solution you have come up with? I am facing this issue as well.

Comment: @jsd Sorry, no. :( I didn't find any "official" solution. Surely we can hack into somewhere, but in a few updates we might get issues as this usually happens. The last idea was to write a little bash script and use it with npm, something like 'sh parse-dot-env.sh && ng build --prod', but we had little time left on the project, we had to move on. If you come up with something, please share ;-)

Comment: I think it should really be built on top of webpack. I had success when the app is served w webpack.

Comment: I just used a JSON file - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/sharing-secret-environment-variables-with-google-cloud-build-and-angular-universal-7e3

Answer (score 2):

This question becomes also more and more important, when we want to containerize angular applications.

My research lead me to an idea, where I have to write a little node.js or typescript program, using dotenv for reading .env file and create the environment.ts file at buildtime, before starting ng serve.
You can create entries in the package.json like this:

```
...
"config": "ts-node set-env.ts",
"server": "npm run config && ng serve"
...
```

and run it with

```
npm run server
```

Here is a good explanation with an example typescript file:
https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I'd like to see something more promising. I do these hack and I am OK with them but as long as I could not find any solution. Do you find a better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a config file and populate in Run-time.

1) create a File(app-config.json) in assets folder with your variables

```
{ "servicesUrl": "https://localhost:8080/api"}
```

2) create a service (AppConfigService ) to read the file.

```
@Injectable()
    export class AppConfigService {
        private appConfig;

        constructor (private injector: Injector) { }

        loadAppConfig() {
            let http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

            return http.get('/assets/app-config.json')
            .toPromise()
            .then(data => {
                this.appConfig = data;
            })
        }

        get config() {
            return this.appConfig;
        }
```

3) Next we need to tell our application to execute the loadAppConfig() method of our service.

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';

@NgModule({
   ...,
    providers: [
        AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFn,
            multi: true,
            deps: [AppConfigService]
        }
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4) create a function called "appInitializerFn"  to call our service in AppModule (app.module.ts)

```
const appInitializerFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
    return () => {
        return appConfig.loadAppConfig();
    }
};

...

@NgModule({
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

5) import environment and use it :example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';

@Injectable()
export class DataContextService {
    basePath: string;

    constructor (private environment: AppConfigService, private http: HttpClient) {
        this.basePath = environment.config.servicesBasePath;
    }

    getNames() {
        return this.http.get(this.basePath + '/names/');
    }
}
```

for more information please see:
[link](https://www.technouz.com/4746/how-to-use-run-time-environment-variables-in-angular/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but my `.env` file has no json, and I want to configure it at **build** time, not at run time.

Comment: have you your backend and front-end in the same project? you could try to reference to another env file

Comment: If this is important, they are in different folders on the same machine. In fact, there's several angular apps, running independently and using the same API, also local config, configs for 2 dev servers, prod config. So there's some copypasting happening, hence the question.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to use variables in build time you could use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE. For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Comment: Yes.... but it doesn't really run on the server, it actually runs in the browser. :)

Comment: if you want to use procces.env you must run your angular app on node server.

Comment: maybe you can  try with Gulp and manage it with [gulp-environments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-environments)